# How do I completely delete the "Chrome Remote Desktop Viewer" that comes with Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins

I had installed Google Chrome (Version 42) some weeks back because it looked like it was needed for some corporate purposes.

Today I happened to go to the about:plugins page and noticed that it came with a "Chrome Remote Desktop Viewer" plugin that was enabled by default. It looks as shown below:

[image]

I would like all binaries related to this plugin to be completely removed from my OS (Win 7); is this possible, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: This is more of a question for SuperUser than InfoSec. I have voted to migrate for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome's plugins are stored in one folder and use one file to function *properly*.

Unlike Firefox and Internet Explorer, Google Chrome does not store its plugins in `Windows Registry`.

I pick this information to you from the [official documentation](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory):

So you need only to locate your plugin and delete it.

For that, open Google Chrome browser and type in the URL: `chrome://version/`; on that page, this parameter is the one that interests you: `Profile Path`. If it is `C:\Users\<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` then your plugins storage directory is: `C:\Users\<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`

Note that you can access your profile on Chrome by clicking on `Start` and type `%USERPROFILE%`.

For the file I mentioned, it is [Preferences](https://support.google.com/a/answer/187948?hl=en) file  that your browser uses to load the plugins you installed, but you do not have to delete any entry as it will be done by the system for you when `Chrome Remote Desktop Viewer` plugin is  removed from that folder.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old post, and perhaps when it was offered there was not a simpler solution, but at least in Chrome v61, I was able to delete the extension using the trashcan icon on the extensions page. I don't see that in the screenshot above.

To the OP, is it that you could only disable but not delete it then? Or would anyone perhaps tell me that the delete I've done is not enough?

Finally, and curiously, the Google support site offers a page (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) with a section labelled "remove chrome remote desktop" (there was no anchor within the page that I could offer). What's curious is that they refer only to using "add/remove programs" (in Windows) or an uninstall (in mac). Not sure why those docs don't propose simply doing the delete of the extension, either.

I'm prepared to be schooled if it's I that am missing something. :-)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I think you are correct in that there was not as simple a solution at that point, and I'm actually inclined to believe that they are two completely independent programs. However, future readers may come across this question and your answer solves a similar, but current, problem.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to open the program, click the "hamburger" (3 dots in the top right corner) and select "Uninstall..." from that menu.

You cannot just delete this, it MUST be uninstalled properly, since it needs to also remove the host services it spawns.